# Symbolic Links for series of folders

Tags: powershell, symlink

I am trying to write a deployment script which will sniff a set of folders (always being updated) for `.exe` files and create a shortcut for each in a target directory for all users on a machine (a vendor supplies price guides and each guide has its own source folder and files and for end-user ease, our Help Desk creates a shortcut for each price guide).

Process is currently manual and I am looking to automate it. The source files are always being updated so I would prefer to not hard-code any of the names.

I can run the following to generate all of the `.exe` files that I wish to create shortcuts for:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\dirSupportFiles -Include "*.exe" -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "List of Shortcut Files: $_" -Verbose }
```

Result:

```
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\ESRDPC151\ESMGR151.EXE
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\ESRDPC151\FujitsuNetCOBOL.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\ESRDPC160\ESMGR160.EXE
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\ESRDPC170\ESMGR170.EXE
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\HHAPRC152\HHDRV152.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\HOSPC16B\HOSP_PC_FY16_V162.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\INPPC17B\INP_PC_FY17.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\INPPRC154\INDRV154.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\INPPRC161\INDRV161.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\IPFPRC150\IPF.EXE
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\IPFPRC160\IPF_PC_FY16.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\IRFPRC150\IRF.EXE
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\IRFPRC160\IRF_PC_FY16.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\LTCHPC15D\LTCH_PC_FY15.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\LTCHPC16B\LTCH_PC_FY16.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\SNFPC16E\SNF_PC_FY16.exe
VERBOSE: List of Shortcut Files: C:\dirSupportFiles\SNFPC17B\SNF_PC_FY17.exe
```

So in order to adapt this into a script to write the shortcuts, I have tried to enlist the `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink` cmdlet to do this but I am having issues getting it to work how I want it to:

```
##variable defined for copying data into user appdata folders
$Destination = "C:\users\"

##variable defined for copying data into user appdata folders
$Items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Exclude public,ADMIN*,defaultuser0

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\dirSupportFiles -Include "*.exe" -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Item -Itemtype SymbolicLink -Path $Item\Desktop\ -Name "NAME OF OBJECT" -Target $_
    }
```

About `NAME OF OBJECT`: I am hoping to have write the shortcut name the same as the file name but I cannot get it to work.  When I run the command it will only write the one shortcut because each time it tries to write the next, the script errors out with a `ResourceExists` exception.

Does anyone have any input to this or if there is another method I should be considering?  I am open to other methods but am ultimately wrapping this using the PS App Deploy Toolkit.

Comment: `{New-Item -Itemtype SymbolicLink -Path $Item\Desktop\ -Name $_.Name -Target $_.FullName}`

Comment: Thanks Swonkie, that did the trick! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `ForEach-Object` process block, the `$_` magic variable to refer not just to the name alone, but it holds a reference to a [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object, meaning that you can use it to access multiple attributes of the corresponding file:

```
$Destination = "C:\users"

foreach($Item in Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Exclude public,ADMIN*,defaultuser0){

    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\dirSupportFiles -Include "*.exe" -Recurse |ForEach-Object {
        New-Item -Itemtype SymbolicLink -Path $Item\Desktop\ -Name $_.BaseName -Target $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Notice the use of `$_.BaseName` and `$_.FullName` inside the `ForEach-Object` block

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Works great now!